# Swiftmailer not sending immediately

Tags: symfony, configuration, ubuntu-14.04, swiftmailer

I have successfully configure my symfony webapp to sending email using SMTP. But all my sending email are being put into the `spool` directory.

This should only occurs whem there is an error in the sending. Is that correct?

But if I execute the command `swiftmailer:spool:send  --env=prod`, all my emails are sending correctly.

Why my server are not sending the email immediately?
Is that because I fixed an error? Is there any way to fix this?

swiftmailer:

```
spool:
    type: file
    path: %kernel.root_dir%/spool
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A just add the command `swiftmailer:spool:send` into `crontab`. This step wasn't clear on [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html).

Answer (score 6):

In case somebody is processing emails via message-queue (symfony/messenger), using memory spool is preferred option. However, memory spool is processed only on `Kernel::terminate` event. This event will never occur on long running console worker.

This kernel event is invoking `Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate()` method. You can invoke this method manually by dispatching your own event & subscribing above mentioned method to it.

**`src/App/Email/Events.php`**

```
<?php

namespace App\Email;

class Events
{
    public const UNSPOOL = 'unspool';
}
```

**`config/services.yml`**

```
services:    
    App\Email\AmqpHandler:
      tags: [messenger.message_handler]

    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener:
        tags:
            - name: kernel.event_listener
              event: !php/const App\Email\Events::UNSPOOL
              method: onTerminate
```

*your message-queue worker*
**`src/App/Email/AmqpHandler.php`**

```
<?php

namespace App\Email;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

class AmqpHandler
{
    /** @var EventDispatcherInterface */
    private $eventDispatcher;

    /** @var Swift_Mailer */
    private $mailer;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function __invoke($emailMessage): void
    {
        //...
        $message = (new Swift_Message($subject))
            ->setFrom($emailMessage->from)
            ->setTo($emailMessage->to)
            ->setBody($emailMessage->body, 'text/html');

        $successfulRecipientsCount = $this->mailer->send($message, $failedRecipients);
        if ($successfulRecipientsCount < 1 || count($failedRecipients) > 0) {
            throw new DeliveryFailureException($message);
        }

        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(Events::UNSPOOL);
    }
}
```

You can read about **symfony/messenger** [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can force to flush the spool.
For example :

```
$mailer = $this->container->get('mailer');
$mailer->send($message);

$spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
$transport = $this->container->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');
if ($spool and $transport) $spool->flushQueue($transport);
```

Check also your spool configuration in config.yml.

If you have :

```
swiftmailer:
    ....
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

mails get sent on the kernel terminate event (so at the end of the page)

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this in some cases. But when the `FOSUserBundle` send the email, the Queue isn't flushed. I'm using spool typy as `file`. So the email is only sended when I manually flush. In my old machine this was done automatically.

Comment: and you do not want to use memory ? (at least for FOSUserBundle)

Comment: Why use `file` and `memory`?

Comment: See the start of http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html for advantage of file spool (but you must flush ...)

Comment: Yes. Now I undestand. I'm doing a migration from a machine that other person configured, so it's my first time configuring a Symfony from nothing. It's not clear that you SHOULD add the command to the cron tab to get the emails sent.