# Symfony swiftmail won't send from code

Tags: php, symfony

Been struggling with swiftmail for a while now.
I have a linux server and properly working sendmail. Sending mail from command line works.
And sending with swiftmail via command line works as well so the configuration must be OK.
But from code it doesn't. Must have read all the issues of this and I'm totally confused what's going on.

The token is created OK and everything seems to work. No errors in logs. But the mail just doesn't come. I have tried to send to different domains as well. And as I said, it works from command line with mail and swiftmail commands like this:

```
bin/console swiftmailer:email:send --subject="Test" --body="test" --from="info@domain.com" --to="test@anotherdomain.com"
```

Here is the current code:

```
$mailer = $this->get('mailer');
$message = $mailer->createMessage()
    ->setSubject('You forgot password')
    ->setFrom('info@domain.com')
    ->setTo($username)
    ->setBody('You forgot your password. Go and change it from http://url.com/change-password/'.$user->getConfirmationToken());

    $mailer->send($message);
```

Here is config.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
transport:  sendmail
host:       /usr/sbin/sendmail -bs
```

Comment: how are you runing your app, is this localhost or server, dev or prod ?
something like this in your config? `swiftmailer:
    delivery_addresses: ['muchemail@email.pl']`

Comment: You need to flush your queue. . take a look at this answer.  .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802225/swiftmailer-not-sending-immediately

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by disabling spool on swift mailer.

You didn't specify the Symfony version you are using. If you are using Symfony 4, there should be a config file in /config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml

Here is mine:

```
swiftmailer:
url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
#spool:
    #type: 'memory'
    #type: file
    #path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/spool'
```

Comment: Hi. As for answer for this and for hanish above, the queue is disabled. I can verify this in command line when trying to flush the spool. (says that spool is disabled)
So this cannot be the issue.

The version of swiftmail seems to be  5.4.3
I believe Symfony version is 3.