# When sending emails from a worker, they are not send untill an exception is thrown

Tags: symfony, queue, swiftmailer, symfony-3.4

I'm placing several mails in a queue. When I run the worker, it will process all the mails successfully, however they are not send. When I add a mail that triggers an exception, the worker is killed, and all the mails are being send.

When I run `bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send` after handling the mails with the worker, it will show:

`0 emails sent`

Also tried to `forceSend()`, did not work as well.

The worker:

```php
class SendQueuedMailWorker
{
    /**
     * @var Mailer
     */
    private $mailer;


    public function __construct(
        Mailer $mailer
    ) {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }


    public function handle(SendQueuedMailCommand $command): void
    {

        $user = $command->getUser();

        $mailContext = [
            'user' => $user
        ];

        $message = $this->mailer->compose(
            'mail_template',
            $mailContext,
            null,
            $user->getEmail()
        );


        if ($this->mailer->send($message) === false) {
            throw QueuedMailNotSentException::withId($command->getReference());
        }
    }
}
```

Swiftmailer:

```
swiftmailer:
  transport:          '%mailer_transport%'
  encryption:         '%mailer_encryption%'
  host:               '%mailer_host%'
  port:               '%mailer_port%'
  username:           '%mailer_user%'
  password:           '%mailer_password%'
  delivery_addresses: '%mailer_delivery_addresses%'
  spool:              { type: 'memory' }
  disable_delivery:   '%mailer_disable_delivery%'
```

There are no error messages thrown when the queue is being consumed.

Console output:

```sh
Consuming from mailsend queue
[1] Processing payload {"reference":2016320254, "user":"John"}
[1] processed with result: true
[2] Processing payload {"reference":2019990645, "user":"Doe"}
[2] processed with result: true
```

How do I get the mails to be send immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51730638/11830313

Turns out spooled mails that are being handled by a worker will only get send on `Kernel::terminate`.

This does seem like quit a drastic solution for me, so if anyone has a different solution for the issue at hand, I will be more than happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

**Final solution:**

Create `MailerSpoolFlusher`. Inject the `\Swift_MemorySpool` and `\Swift_Transport` into it.

In the `MailerSpoolFlusher` add:

```php
public function flush()
{
    $this->spool->flushQueue($this->transport);
}
```

Then inject the `MailerSpoolFlusher` into the worker, and call the `flush()` after `$mailer->send()`.

Works like a charm, and no need to initiate a `onTerminate`.