# Swiftmailer and Symfony Messenger not working with AMQP and rabbitmq within docker

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, amqp, swiftmailer

I am desperate with a task.

I bassicly tried everything and can't get to solution.

I am trying to send mail with Swiftmailer asynchronously by using the SymMessenger, AMQP, rabbitmq with docker.

Everything is is installed, but within API platform I always get an error I could not handle.

The idea is to trigger __invoke function on persisting MyEntity entity. I tried with mailcatcher, everything is working so I tried with async examples.

> **"Attempted to load class "AMQPConnection" from the global namespace.\nDid you forget a "use" statement for "PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection"?",",**

I configured parameters starting with docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  rabbitmq: # The RabbitMQ container.
      container_name: rabbitmq_container
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: scripts/provision/docker/rabbitmq/Dockerfile
      volumes:
        - ./scripts/provision/docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql:cached
      ports: [5672, 15672]

  container_php:
      container_name: container_php
      build: ./scripts/provision/docker/php-fpm/
      expose:
        - 9000
      volumes:
        - .:/var/www/html:cached
      environment:
        - MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/%2f/messages
```

My *.env* file

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672/%2f/messages
```

messenger.yml file

```
framework:
messenger:
    transports:
        # Uncomment the following line to enable a transport named "amqp"
        amqp_: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'

    routing:
        # Route your messages to the transports
      'App\Entity\MyEntity': amqp
```

In DataPersister class I dispatch:

```
private function sendWelcomeEmail(MyEntity $myEntity, MessageBus $messageBus)
{
    $messageBus->dispatch($myEntity);
}
```

And my function in EmailNotificationHandler.

```
public function __invoke(MyEntity $myEntity) :JsonResponse
{

    $message = (new \Swift_Message(
        'New comment on post'
    ))
        ->setFrom('sender@sent.com')
        ->setTo('recipient@recipient.com')
        ->setBody(
            'There is a new comment on post, check it out!',
            'text/html',
            'UTF-8'
        )
    ;

    $mailer->send($message);

    sleep(5);

    echo 'OK';
  }
}
```

When I run following command ***php bin/console messenger:consume amqp*** in the docker container I get:

I run the container with *docker exec -ti rabbitmq_container* command.

And then when I execute entity persist in API platform I got the message from above.
When data persister is activated, it runs sendWelcomeEmail() which has dispatch method and then __invoke.

I changed SwiftMailer transport but I think that is not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens due of *swiftmailer flow*, it sends messages just on `Kernel::terminate` event, but this event will not be occurred on worker process.

To solve this issue, you should:

1. Dispatch `Events::UNSPOOL` event - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51730638/9799016
2. Or use `symfony/mailer` component (symfony >= 4.3) - https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/mailer.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have following error: Socket error: could not connect to host. I have tried everything and my rabbitmq dashboard is working so I think everything is working as it should. What this error could be? @Vlad